# Internalization in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Sorry for my english. I am working on a spring boot application and I have the following situation. I implemented internalization and I created a following configuration class

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {   

  @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("es_ES"));
        return localeResolver;
    }  
   
    @Bean
    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(resourceBundleMessageSource());
        return bean;
    }

    
    @Bean("messageSource")
    public MessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource
                = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
    

}
```

Also I have two properties files `messages.properties` and `messages_us.properties`.

And I defined a User entity class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable {    

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", table = "users", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "{not.field.empty}")
    @NotNull(message = "{not.field.empty}")
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "lastname", table = "users", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "birthday", table = "users")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @NotNull(message = "birthday {not.empty.field}")
    private Date birthday;

}
```

When I try to test validation by calling following endpoint

```
    @PostMapping("/users")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
//code...
}
```

If validation failes, I'm getting all error messages correctly.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1599168856694,
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Not validate field",
    "message": [
        "birthday Obligatory filed"
    ],
    "path": "/api/v1/users"
}
```

But when I use @Valid in a `Service` class like this

```
    @Override
    @Transactional()
    public User saveUser(@Valid User user) { 
//code...
}
```

I don't get the translated messages error messages.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1599169130869,
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Not validate field",
    "message": [
        "roles {not.empty.field}",
        "birthday {not.empty.field}"
    ],
    "path": "/api/v1/users"
}
```

Does anybody knows what's the issue here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your saveUser service method is getting called only from the REST API endpoint method "createUser" which is already validating the USER entity. I do not see any need for using @Valid in the service method argument as well. The rest endpoint is already doing the needful.

This post might help you - https://auth0.com/blog/exception-handling-and-i18n-on-spring-boots-apis/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to implement @Valid in service because for example in endpoint registration I did not use a model user like RequestBody but
if the data is valid I create and save the User, calling the User Service:                       `@PostMapping("/auth/signup")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity<?> signUp(@Valid @RequestBody SignUp signUp) {
        userService.saveUser(...) }                                                                                I will read the post, thanks